# Open modal dialog with confirmation message in form submission handler

Tags: 8

I've a form with few fields and submit button. When user click on Submit button, I do some processing and after which I want to open a confirmation form in ModalDialog with some customised message (dynamic) and "Proceed" & "Cancel" button. If user click on Proceed button, user will be taken to next page and if click on Cancel, the modal will be closed.

I've checked [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/190340/678) and [D.O. Issue for Core Workflow Module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2830584), but these are for opening's Modal using link and not on form submit.

Comment: use ajax in form submit when submit open modal window

Comment: I'm already using ajax submit, but the problem is modal open messages, not form. I've also tried rendering form content and passing, but in that case my form submit is misbehaving.

Comment: Found that similar work is inprogress in [Drupal Core 8.7.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2883755)